# flutter in_app_purchase: How to validate receipts on iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase

I've made flutter app with auto-renewable subscriptions. It works well on Android, but from Appstore i received this letter:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Someone just gives very laconic advise:

```
there are few solutions
- local via library
- local via calling verifyReceipt directly
- server side validation via the same verifyReceipt
```

But I have no idea how to realize this in flutter neither local nor server... (((
Maybe anyone flutter guru can send me step-by-step lesson or so to deal with this quest?
Actually a lot of dart pub libraries (such a `local_auth`, etc) have samples what code one need to write in native - `swift` or `kotlin` to achive a result, but not `in_app_purchase` alas. I really got stucked. Some double-trouble it is.

Comment: This is validating subscriptions https://stackoverflow.com/a/55870013/1319363 . See if it helps in your case